# Visual Studio 2019 Always run OLD version code

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2019

I tried many things that searched on google.

listing I had.

1. Project -> Property -> Debugging -> Debugging = Auto
2. Build -> Configuration Manager -> Check OK "BUILD" option ( Also I checked solution platforms and configs. )
3. Tools -> Option -> Build & Run -> Always Build. and Uncheck "just startup project & dependencys"

Those are what I did to build every pressing F5.

It doesn't work. even though I restart computer or visual studio.

What should I do for it?

ps. My Project is Visual Studio C++ (Empty)

Comment: Don't press F5. Instead enable the build toolbar or press F7 and build your code. if you get errors fix them before trying to debug.

Comment: No I don't get any errors and F7 doesn't work

Comment: Use your file explorer and delete the Debug and Release folder. if that does not work recreate your project.

Comment: I have already did

Comment: Create a new project and re add your code.

Comment: Does your solution have multiple projects or a single one? You run a standard MSVC build and not some visualGDB nonsense, right?

Comment: @ALX23z  Yes I have only one project on solution. And Yes I run with MSVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Looking for days but finally i found a solution.
The first step is to completely delete Visual Studio (installer as well,yes) and then install it again.This time check on "general options" and not "recommended for C++" in the beginning of the installation(Its where you choose the color of the IDE).I know it's sounds..weird.Let me know if it worked for you too!

Comment: When I get that problem, i just gave up my project. thank you for your answer.
(I copied all codes and files, and paste new project)

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to your visual studio having settings that launch the old working code if the current code has some issues.

You could change that setting using the below steps:

> <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Project and Solutions</kbd> > <kbd>Build and Run</kbd>
>
> `Do below settings on the left pull-down menu`
>
> <kbd>On Run, when build or deployment error occurs</kbd> > <kbd>Do not launch</kbd>