# Why does Visual Studio sometimes run using old code?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build

I have (fairly large) C# solution in VS 2019, running with ReSharper. Since a few days - and I can't make out the trigger - the following happens:

I change code, add a breakpoint (not required, but makes the issue show nicely), click "Start" (triggering a build and a run) and the application runs, but **using old code**.

The breakpoint changes to "broken" after the build, which is quick. And the build log is unbelievably short, without any warnings, but also without errors. It lists that the project I made the change in was successfully rebuilt or at least that the build was started.

I thought I may have [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/breakpoint-does-not-hit-with-require-source-files/77984) issue, but the code executed is the old.

Is this a caching issue? Can I get better logs somewhere?

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66404015) (full re-install of VS) the only solution?

EDIT: It appears to be getting worse, by now I have to manually/explicitly rebuild my solution before running (almost) every time. And, if this is any hint: while trying to fix the issue, I deleted the hidden .vs folder (where the. suo files lives) - and it has not been re-created. Shouldn't it have been?

EDIT2: The link from dwcanillas below inspired me to search deeper in my solution folder for any nested .vs folders and, indeed, I found a few - not for every project, but for some. I deleted them all and today so far it appears to be better.

CURRENT SOLUTION (another visual studio voodoo recipe):

- Clean top-level solution
- Close Visual Studio
- Delete all ".vs" folders (hidden, in every solution folder)
- Open Visual Studio
- Rebuild top-level solution

Observed side-effects: Previously unloaded projects will be loaded again. But there's probably more...

Comment: you may want to make sure you didnt disable building before running when there are local changes: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/start-button-doesnt-rebuild-solution/173764

Answer (score -2):

You may have to, though try rebuilding it first, and cleaning the solution as well.